# Class inheritance, appending to array without redefining

Tags: python, inheritance

Here is an example base class:

```
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.properties
        except AttributeError:
            self.properties = []
    def _add_property(self,prop):
        self.properties.append(prop)
    def getProperties(self):
        return self.properties
```

And two classes that inherit from the base class:

```
class ClassValues(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
       BaseClass.__init__(self)
       self._add_property("values")
       # Additional values functionality

class ClassWords(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
       BaseClass.__init__(self)
       self._add_property("words")
       # Addition words functionality
```

If something inherits from both `ClassWords` and `ClassValues`, is there a way to this without the `try` in the base class?

Comment: Ok is there a way to do it without the except

Comment: Why do you use `try` if you always enter the except branch?

Comment: Just replace the whole `try:... except:...` part with `self.properties=[]`.

Comment: That would clear properties if i had a class inherit from both

Comment: Use [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) to check if the attribute exists, as in `hasattr(self, "properties")`. The `try/except` approach is highly discouraged.